# SAS Batch Export (when size matters)

Tags: unix, sas

May go beyond a SAS question, but I recently ran into an issue where the batch environment will not deliver(email) the specific file(xls) due to a size restriction. Obviously I had to move to a flat file, but also noticed that a ".data" file is also the same size (was hoping it would be smaller). Are there smaller file formats that exist (that SAS will support)?

Comment: What's "batch environment"?

Comment: Sorry, UNIX env. with a shell script (bash)

Comment: Alright... so please correct your post (including tags, tirle and body)... thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't really specific enough to be answerable.  SAS supports all kinds of files, but you don't specify what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your version of SAS and the modules you have installed, you may be able to export to .xlsx (compressed) instead of .xls, or create a zip file containing the .xls instead. Try googling for `libname xlsx` for more details.

Comment: As mentioned in my edit comment, was not aware that I could send via zip file